# Open browser with letter opener on docker toolbox - Rails/Docker/Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, docker, rubygems, docker-toolbox

How do I setup the letter opener gem to open mails on the browser using the docker toolbox for windows?

My app runs at `192.168.99.100`, the console shows the mail template but it does not open the browser tab with the content.

Besides that everything is running normally.

I've tried the initializer config `file_uri_scheme` but it does not worked with the values that I tested, like:

```
file://tmp/letter_opener
file:////tmp/letter_opener
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

At [letter opener documentation](https://github.com/ryanb/letter_opener?tab=readme-ov-file#configuration) we have a section called Configuration that mention WSL.

```
LetterOpener.configure do |config|
  # To overrider the location for message storage.
  # Default value is `tmp/letter_opener`
  config.location = Rails.root.join('tmp', 'my_mails')

  # To render only the message body, without any metadata or extra containers or styling.
  # Default value is `:default` that renders styled message with showing useful metadata.
  config.message_template = :light

  # To change default file URI scheme you can provide `file_uri_scheme` config.
  # It might be useful when you use WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) and default
  # scheme doesn't work for you.
  # Default value is blank
  config.file_uri_scheme = 'file://///wsl$/Ubuntu-18.04'
end
```